# Regex pattern to find words in different order

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

**random words 12 pouches 1.5oz (42g) random words** -> I want: 12 pouches 1.5oz (42g)

or

**random words 1.5oz (42g) 12 pouches random words** -> I want: 1.5oz (42g) 12 pouches

So I need a patter to match:

- 1.5oz
- 42g
- 12 pouches.

I have a pattern to match the three of them but alone. The problem is when they are in the same string and in different order.

I think that this is related to lookahead and lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use lookahead and/or lookbehind

```
import re
x = "random words 12 pouches 1.5oz (42g) random words"
patt = re.compile("(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\spouches|oz|g))")
print(patt.findall(x))
```

Comment: Thanks @Transamunos , it worked. I thougth that I need to use lookahead and lookbehind